# Rails combinations of two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

In my Ruby on Rails project I have a `Message` model that has `direction`, `from`, `to` columns. `direction` could be 'incoming' or 'outgoing'.

I want to group messages into conversations by their `from` and `to` fields. Say I have the following messages in my database:

```
{id: 1, direction: 'incoming', from: '10000', to: '2222'}
{id: 2, direction: 'outgoing', from: '2222', to: '10000'}
{id: 3, direction: 'incoming', from: '10001', to: '3333'}
{id: 4, direction: 'outgoing', from: '3333', to: '10001'}
```

In the end I would like to have a hash that looks like `{['10000','2222']=>[message with id 1, message with id 2], ['10001','3333']=>[message with id 3, message with id 4]}`

I've tried `Message.all.group_by{|m| [m.from, m.to]}` but that will give me a hash with keys `[['10000', '2222'], ['2222','10000'],['10001', '3333'], ['3333','10001']]`. Here I have repeated keys even though their orders are different.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
direction = Hash.new

Message.all.each do |message|
  if message.direction == "incoming"
    from = message.from
    to = message.to
  else
    from = message.to
    to = message.from
  end

  direction[[from, to]] ||= []
  direction[[from, to]] << "message with id #{message.id}"
end
```

Now `direction` will be the Hash that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, where `messages` are your messages.

```
messages.group_by do |m|
  m.direction == "incoming" ? [m.from, m.to] : [m.to, m.from]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with group_by still - you just need to be specific about the key you use to group on. Since you don't care about the directionality of the message, be they incoming or outgoing, you can simply group on a sorted list of the from and to. So both 10000 -> 2222. and 2222 -> 10000 becomes grouped under a  hash key of [10000, 2222], and your messages get grouped the way you were expecting.

```
messages = [
  {id: 1, direction: 'incoming', from: '10000', to: '2222'},
  {id: 2, direction: 'outgoing', from: '2222', to: '10000'},
  {id: 3, direction: 'incoming', from: '10001', to: '3333'},
  {id: 4, direction: 'outgoing', from: '3333', to: '10001'}
]

messages = messages.group_by do |x|
  [x[:from], x[:to]].sort
end
```

This will return:

```
{
  ["10000", "2222"]=>[
    {:id=>1, :direction=>"incoming", :from=>"10000", :to=>"2222"},
    {:id=>2, :direction=>"outgoing", :from=>"2222", :to=>"10000"}
  ],
  ["10001", "3333"]=>[
    {:id=>3, :direction=>"incoming", :from=>"10001", :to=>"3333"},
    {:id=>4, :direction=>"outgoing", :from=>"3333", :to=>"10001"}
  ]
 }
```